# Empty enum with generic parameters

Tags: rust, enums

Uninhabited types can be useful as type-level markers, but sometimes I want an uninhabited type which has generic parameters, and rust won't let me make one, because generic parameters must *always* be used, and an enum with no variants *can't* use it's generic parameters.

```rs
/// This is fine. Ordinary uninhabited type
enum MyEmptyType {}
/// This is fine too. Ordinary generic enum
enum MyGenericType<T,U> {
  Foo(T),
  Bar(T,U),
  Baz(U),
}
/// This won't compile. Parameter T must be used
enum MyGenericEmptyType<T, U> {}
```

I could always make a variant containing `PhantomData`, but then it's no longer an empty type! I could just give it private fields to prevent users from constructing it, but I want to hold onto that type-level guarantee that type is empty, rather than just making it impossible to construct in user code.

Answer (score 1):

While the most direct way to make an uninhabited type is indeed with an empty enum, you can also make a type empty by putting it in a struct alongside another uninhabited type (e.g. [`!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html), the (currently unstable) canonical uninhabitable type):

```rs
#![feature(never_type)]

struct MyGenericEmptyType<T, U> {
  // this ensures the type is empty.
  never: !,
  // this ensures the parameters are used, but it doesn't really need to use PhantomData,
  // since the type can't be instantiated anyway.
  phantom: PhantomData<fn(T) -> U>,
}
```

Think of it like this: in order for an instance of this struct to exist, it must contain an instance of `!`, which cannot exist, so the struct cannot exist.
The main downside is that unlike with an empty enum, you can't directly use an empty match on this type (The compiler doesn't check deep enough to see that the type is uninhabited, so it says `missing match arm: type MyGenericEmptyType<T, U> is non-empty`). But you can still match on the `never` field.

```rs
fn any<T>() -> T { panic!() }
fn main() {
  let foo : MyGenericEmptyType<A,B> = any();
  // we can't just do `match foo {}`. 
  match foo.never {}
}
```

Even better though, you could implement a conversion to `!`:

```rs
impl<T,U> From<MyGenericEmptyType<T, U>> for ! {
    fn from(value: MyGenericEmptyType<T, U>) -> ! {
        value.never
    }
}
```